# Where to get Credits used by particular session_id in Snowflake

Tags: cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am looking for an option to get the credit usage by specific session_id in Snowflake. is it possible to get the same? as i understand all credits are charged based on warehouse level. so curious if we can get those credits OR cost in USD for particular Session_id?

Answer (score 0):

Session_id and credits_used_cloud_services are fields returned from

SELECT * FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY"
WHERE START_TIME > '2022-2-01'

Comment: 0


@Larry C

Its not the complete credit usage as i understand its just cloud Service Credits, i need Compute credits used by particular query/Session, which seems impossible i guess..

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible to find the **compute credits** used by a session unless the session runs the queries in a dedicated warehouse.

As you mentioned, compute credits are charged based on how long a warehouse runs (stays online/operational). So it's not possible to distribute these credits to the queries. You can find how many concurrent queries were running on the warehouse and then share the credits evenly for each query, but this will not be a fair distribution. A query may use less resources and take a longer time to execute. In this case, "sharing the credits evenly between concurrent queries" will ignore this and evaluate this query as the most expensive one. Thus, the session executed that "slow" query will pay most of the bill :)

You may dedicate a warehouse to the session if you need to bill/record compute credits per session (or per user).